# What does "{$F 'filename'}" mean exactly?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

In [DWScript documentation](https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/InclusionDirectives#Source_Code_Inclusions) we can see "{$F 'filename'}", but I don't understand what it means. Is it possible to describe It?

Comment: Perhaps it's this: https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/FirstSteps#Filters

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It is true. Thanx. (^_^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F is a bit like $I in that it includes source from another file. The difference is that where $I will include the other file "verbatim" without any changes (and thus that file is expected to be Pascal source), $F will include it after filtering the file.

The filtering mechanism is rather arbitrary, as basically you attach a filter component to the compiler that will take a string as input and return a filtered string as output. So you can think of filters as an open pre-processing mechanism.

An example of filter is the HTML filter that introduces support for a php-like syntax, but where the language is Pascal rather than php (you can see an example in [this article](http://delphitools.info/2013/08/13/dwscript-webserver-in-the-metered-cloud/) or in the DWScript Web Server demo, look in the [Demos/Data/www](https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Demos/Data/www) folder), where a $F can f.i. be used to include a CSS file inline in the output.